# Processing with State and Timers

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Are there any guidelines or limitations for using stateful processing and timers with the Beam Dataflow runner (as of v2.1.0)? Things such as limitations on the size of state or frequency of updates etc.? The candidate streaming pipeline would use state and timers extensively for user session state, with Bigtable as durable storage.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some general advice for your use case

- Please aggregate multiple elements then set a timer.
- Please don't create a timer per element, which would be excessive.
- Try and aggregate state, instead of accumulating large amount of state. I.e. aggregate as a sum and count, instead of storing every number when trying to compute a mean.
- Please consider [session windows](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing#session-windows) for this use case.
- In dataflow, state is not supported for merging windows. It is for beam.
- Please use state according to your access pattern, i.e. [BagState](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/util/state/BagState.html) for blind writes.

Here is an informative blog post with some more info on state "[Stateful processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html)."

Comment: Thank you. Due to lack of support for stateful DoFn with merging windows in Apache Beam, I'm considering using the global window and clear state using a timer. How significant is the overhead of keeping the "empty" state cells in the global window in Dataflow?

Comment: Thomas I have the same problem, and am considering the same. I have been looking for attaching a TTL to the state, but can't find it anywhere. I may have to manually do this.