# Dataflow: Stateful processing performance considerations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am considering to use dataflow with a persistent MapState

From https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html is says:

> You can dig into how a particular runner manages state

But I have been unable to locate the docs which discuss this for Dataflow.

I did find [Processing with State and Timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246233/processing-with-state-and-timers)
Which suggests

> not collecting a large amount of state

If I have missed the relevant docs; more than happy to be pointed in their direction.

1.) How does Dataflow store Persistent state?
Does it save it in Bigtable? On a disk somewhere? Something else totally? Is their a way to chose a method which could be appropriate to the specific work load?

2.) Is it possible to put any numbers around `large` in this case?
If my stream is grouped into 500 different documents; and there can be up to 100 000 keys in each of those document's Persistent Maps; is that a potential good or poor use case?

Thanks

Comment: There is no really such information can be found online. Then the only way to roughly know answer to the second question is do a load test (and could just be very costly, of course).

Also, I double if there is really an even estimation to answer your second question, factors that affect scalability of one component in Dataflow are too many.

Comment: Pondering over this question for some time as well. I'm actually in the process of designing different load tests and I will get back here with concrete results.

Comment: Also curious how dataflow persists the state. It would be nice if we could implement our own backend of persisting state for optimization purpose.

Comment: especially considering the the state is per Key. and each key will be processed by 1 worker, it would make sense to have a worker local copy of the state with a backup somewhere else for fault tolerance